# hide and show div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to show and then hide div but when i click the button it do not work for the first time, when i click second time it works normally.
i want that it works on first click.

HTML

```
    <p>Click the button</p>
    <button onclick="myFunc()">Try it</button>
    <div id="divi">
     Div region
    </div>
```

CSS

```
     #divi {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 50px 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #ccc;
        margin-top:20px;
        display:none;
     }
```

Javascript

```
       function myFunc() {
        var dv = document.getElementById('divi');
        if (dv.style.display ==='none') {
        dv.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
         dv.style.display = 'none';
         }
         }
```

Here is the pen:   https://codepen.io/animaxf/pen/xdVVbK

Comment: When you click the button for the first time, it sets `display: none`, then the second time `display: block`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because technically, the style attribute is empty so `style.display` is actually `null`. So it first of all makes it `display:none;` on first click.

If you change the JavaScript to be:

```
function myFunc() {
  var dv = document.getElementById('divi');
  if (dv.style.display === 'block') {
    dv.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    dv.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Basically checking it is block first - it will work.

```js
function myFunc() {
    var dv = document.getElementById('divi');
    if (dv.style.display === 'block') {
        dv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        dv.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#divi {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-top:20px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button</p>

<button onclick="myFunc()">Try it</button>

<div id="divi">
Div region
</div>
```

Comment: This answer seems a bit of a hack and will only work on divs that start off hidden

Answer (score 2):

First click let it fall to the `else` statement and display it.

After that you are in a good loop.

```js
function myFunc() {
    var dv = document.getElementById('divi');
    if (dv.style.display == 'block') {
        dv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        dv.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#divi {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-top:20px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click the button</p>

<button onclick="myFunc()">Try it</button>

<div id="divi">
Div region
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this 
`<div id="divi" style="display:none">`

The first time, display is not defined for your div

Answer (score 0):

When you click for the first time there is no style applied (dv.style.display = "") hence, dv.style.display!== 'none' becomes true and dv.style.display = 'none' gets applied.

```js
function myFunc() {
    var dv = document.getElementById('divi');
  
    if (dv.style.display !=='none'&& dv.style.display !=="") {
        dv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        dv.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#divi {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-top:20px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click the button</p>

<button onclick="myFunc()">Try it</button>

<div id="divi">
Div region
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `display` property set when you click the first time. Just switched the properties – it will work.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRddvd

Answer (score 0):

The first time you click the button, the CSS property `display` doesn't set yet, therefore when click occurs it checks rather `dv.style.display !== 'none'` while actually `dv.style.display === ''`

You can fix this in your code, or you can simply change the CSS as it is more elegant solution. Just apply `display: block` (or `display: none` according to your wishful starting state) to `#divi` inside it's CSS definition.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you change the style of the div, but the `display:none` attribute is inside the class element. So, the first time the div have not the display attribute and it declare it as `none`. To fix this, put `style="display:none;` on the div instead of declaring it inside the css file

Answer (score 0):

When you first load the page, the class is undeclared meaning that you statement `if (dv.style.display !=='none')` will return true and then apply a display propert `dv.style.display = 'none';`

Instead, you should use `if (dv.style.display =='block')` to check whether it is shown.

```js
function myFunc() {
    var dv = document.getElementById('divi');
    if (dv.style.display =='block') {
        dv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        dv.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#divi {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-top:20px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click the button</p>

<button onclick="myFunc()">Try it</button>

<div id="divi">
Div region
</div>

</body>
```